# How to boot from USB when no bootable drives show up?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, usb, startup, ssd

I bought a 2012 iMac about 3 years and immediately upgraded to an SSD, but the read/write speads maxed out at about USB3 speeds, so I just booted it from USB the whole time.

Fast-forward to about 6 months ago, I bought a new laptop and planned to sell the computer, but I wanted to keep the SSD and just sell it with the internal drive.

The internal drive booted up one time then died, but it apparently set itself as the primary boot drive (??). I don't know about that, but booting it with the SSD plugged into USB stopped working after that–never had an issue before, it just always booted as if the external drive was the only one.

It's been sitting in storage, but we're moving so I really want to get rid of it. No matter what drive is plugged in, I just get the grey screen of death, and hitting option button doesn't bring up bootable drives like it should. I also can't restart in safe mode or recovery mode. I thought maybe it was that the bluetooth keyboard never properly connects, so I went out and bought a USB keyboard, but still never got it to work.

The SSD works just fine and I've had no problems booting my laptop from it and using it as extra storage.

Is there anyway to give it priority to boot from over the internal drive? Something I can control from another computer? Is there some other way to open bootable drives other than the option button on the keyboard? Or some other way to force-boot from external?

Comment: Did you buy an Apple USB keyboard or generic Windows? often WIn kbds won't trigger the startup chooser at boot. idk why.

Comment: It was a generic one. So do you think an Apple USB keyboard might be able to trigger it? On my other (working) computer and with a different bluetooth keyboard, I was always able to trigger it, and this bluetooth keyboard should be connected in the same way. Is it possible that bluetooth just isn't getting connected?

Comment: Unfortunately, any/all of the above is possible, but not easy to diagnose.

Comment: Yeah, understandable. Thanks for the suggestion..I'll see if I can get my hands on a usb apple keyboard